# Calculating Range coverage

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm putting together a sheet that includes two data columns, '**Min Value**' and '**Max Value**'.  All values between Min and Max values are consider the **'Range'** of each entry.  The goal of the sheet is to expose how well each range is covered, ie. The number of entries that cover each range.

This is how the data looks more or less.  Potentially more varying.

```
Model | Min | Max 
c4 #3 | 0.5 | 0.75 
x4 #4 | 0.65| 0.87  
c4 #5 | 0.72| 1.02
```

Is there any possible way to get this data out of Excel?  I'm thinking the best representation might be some type of graph that has the Range Values on the *X Axis* and the number of times that range is covered on the *Y Axis*.

```
  3|             -----
   |
  2|       ----           ----------   
#  |
  1|   ----    --     ----              --- 
   |
  0|_______________________________________
   0     .5     1     1.5     2     2.5
                     Inches
```

*In case you were wondering I want to put gather a sheet that will help climbers evaluate their rack of [camming devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring-loaded_camming_device) to determine which ranges they need to beef up.*

Comment: You can get any data out of excel, the question is what will be useful to the user (which we can't judge), and what the data actually looks like (we don't have a sample). Creating a histogram is [easy enough](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/present-your-data-in-a-histogram-HA010342785.aspx), but depending on how ranges interact, or how you want to show them, you may need a different solution. We need more details to answer.

Comment: @jmac updated with sample data. Obviously it could be there could be any combination of values (with exact duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a chart similar to your example with Excel.  Simply use a stacked bar chart and modify your formatting options.  Here's a sample:

[image: camming device ranges]

I added one additional column named range (=max-min) for the range bar.